# Regex character recognition

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I have a comment string where a user can type "@someusername" anywhere in the comment. When this happens a user list will be shown until a space is typed at the end of the username. I have a regex that is working except that I can't get it to return true when the @ symbol is typed in by itself. I have to type in @ and then another character to make it return true. So the basics are, I need a regex that will return true if and while:

- @ is typed at the beginning of the comment
- @ is typed and is preceded by a space (so they could type test@test.com and it wouldn't return true)
- After @ can take any characters, but will close when a space is typed

Right now I have the following:

```
$scope.userList = function(comment) {
  pattern = /(?:^|\s)@\S+$/;
  if(pattern.test(comment)) {
    $scope.usersShow = true;
  }
  else {
    $scope.usersShow = false;
  }
};
```

This works except for immediately returning true when @ is typed in the ways that I mentioned, and it doesn't close until a space and character is typed after the username. Any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: `$scope.usersShow = pattern.test(comment)` is more readable, no? ) BTW, why `pattern` is defined as a global variable?

Comment: How about: `/(?:^|\s)@\S*$/`

Comment: @raina77ow thank you I edited it and that is much better.

Comment: @anubhava that is working great. The only thing that isn't working is having the user list close immediately when a space is typed after the username. Do you know how I could fix that?

Comment: Can you tell me what is value of `comment` variable in that situation?

Comment: @anubhava it could basically be anything. Any string. So it can be any string with one or many usernames in it.

Comment: well `/(?:^|\s)@\S*$/` will certainly match @ followed by 0 or more non-space characters

Comment: It works perfectly when I run it in a regex tester, that is what is so strange. Does ng-change recognize white space characters? I'm wondering if that is the problem.

Comment: @anubhava That is the problem. ng-change doesn't fire on a white space character. Your solution is perfect for what I needed. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about `ng-change`

Comment: @anubhava No problem at all. It was my fault for not catching that.

Comment: @sturoid - if ng-change doesn't fire on whitespace character, how do you know when a space is typed to finish it?

Comment: @sin I had to add ng-trim="false" to the text box. It makes it so ng-change recognizes whitespace and doesn't just trim it off.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your regex to: `/^|\s)@\S*$/`. The * after \S means "zero or more of the last character" while you had a + which is "one or more of the last character.

Comment: Thank you. Someone gave this answer in the comments. It works great.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the completed solution based on answers above and some tweaking I did:

HTML:

```
input.comment-text ng-model="comment.text" ng-change="showUserList(comment.text) ng-trim="false"
```

JS:

```
$scope.showUserList = function(comment) {
  var pattern = /(?:^|\s)@\S*$/;
  $scope.usersShow = pattern.test(comment);
};
```